# Programming in C: Exit endless loop if written inside

Tags: c, while-loop, exit-code

I would need to exit this loop if a new relation is added!
As long as it is empty or "Enter" is pressed, it needs to keep going.

```
CODE:
static char input[100];

int main()
{
  printf("Press Ctrl+c to Exit!\n");
  while(1)
  {
    //Input (stdin) and output (stdout) declared in <stdio.h> library
    fputs("esp>", stdout);
    fgets(input,100,stdin);

    if(input != 0) //here I can not change it !!!
      return 1;
  }
return 0; 
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Press Ctrl+c to Exit!
esp> (If "enter" is pressed) keep going
esp>
esp> s ( if something wrong is written, exit) else, keep going
```

Comment: I do not understand what your question is. It sounds like you want to exit from the loop based on some condition, but your code is already doing that. That's what the `if` statement does; if `input !=0`, it breaks out of the loop and returns 1 immediately. Otherwise, it keeps looping. So...what is your question? What part of the code doesn't work?

Comment: You know that you can break a loop with `break;`, do you? So you should clarify what your problem is

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt esp> s ( if something wrong is written, exit) else, keep going
 I need program to be inside while loop, as long as as there is no inputs

Comment: `if( strcmp( input, "\n" ) != 0 ) ...` ? (might be `"\r\n" in win)

Comment: @CodyGray If condition is not working properly. I need  while loop to be runing as long as its empty. Otherwise, i need it to exit, and do something else.

Comment: @CodyGray testing an array with `!= 0` is always true, it will never exit

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check for empty input, try this?

```
while(1)
{
    fputs("esp> ", stdout );
    fgets( input, 100, stdin );

    if( input[0] != '\n' && strlen(input) )
    {
        // Do something with input
    }
}
```